# app.post() is not working plz help tried everything

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

the express code is given below:-
no matter what i try i get the res.body as ({})
i cannot find the error
i even checked the docs but to no avail

```
const app = express();
const Blog = require('./models/blog');

//to enable post requests

app.use(express.json()); 
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended : true}));


// for views 
// views enable dynamiiic content loading more suitable for real life website
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.listen(3000);


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    
    // res.sendFile('./html-pages/index.html', {root : __dirname});
    
    //using views and sending objects
    //pasing values to ejs files
    res.redirect('/blogs');
});


//post method
app.post('/blogs', (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
    
    // const blog = new Blog(req.body);
});
app.get('/blogs/create', (req, res) => {
    res.render('create', {title : 'Create a Blog'})
})
```

the form code :- ejs file
this contains the form used to submit a blog=

```
        <div class="create-blog content">
            <form action="/blogs" method="POST">
                <label for="title">Blog title</label>
                <input type="text" id="title" name:"title" required>
                <label for="snippet">Blog Snippet</label>
                <input type="text" id="snippet" name:"snippet" required>
                <label for="body">Blog Body</label>
                <textarea id="body" required name:"body"></textarea>
                <button>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: have u use the body-parser middleware ? app.use(express.bodyParser());

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to understand the question, but I see errors in your frontend form.
Should look something like this:

```
<form action="/blogs" method="POST">
  <label for="title">Blog title</label>
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" required />
  <label for="snippet">Blog Snippet</label>
  <input type="text" id="snippet" name="snippet" required />
  <label for="body">Blog Body</label>
  <input type="text" name="body" required />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Note that only those fields will be sent in the POST body that has `name` attribute.

And use bodyparser on backend side.

Answer (score 0):

It looks there is no issue in your javascript file. But in handlebars inside `<input>` tag you have to use `=` instead of `:` that might work fine. like `<input name="title" id="title"/>`